# array collection set foreign keys

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, foreign-keys, arraycollection

I have an array collection set as a datagrid's dataprovider. I'm pulling content from my relational database and 2 of the columns in the grid appear as foreign keys.

How do I go about replacing the foreign key id with information from the other table?

I'm guessing I need to do some sort of: for each, but I'm really not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would be using Itemrenderer's for those two columns where you will replace those two foreign key id's with the respective labels(values etc.). Further details on Itemrenderers: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-1c32bcb9124deadc3e9-8000.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did get everything working using itemrenderer's, but ended up just rewriting my query with a couple of LEFT JOINs which worked a bit better for my project.